# Sinatra with Datamapper throws undefined method `add_domain_type' for Psych:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper, nomethoderror

I'm working on a pretty simple sinatra + datamapper app, and it was launching and working just fine yesterday. I attempted to introduce some seed data into the db, and started getting this strange error on launch. I reverted back to pre-seed code, and the error persists. I've noticed that commenting out the include DataMapper::Resource in my model makes the app run again. here's the error:

/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dm-serializer-1.2.2/lib/dm-serializer/to_yaml.rb:15:in `included': undefined method`add_domain_type' for Psych:Module (NoMethodError) ... Any ideas?

```
#app.rb:

require 'sinatra'
require 'pry'
require_relative 'models'

helpers do
  def content_path(file)
    File.join("images", file)
  end
end

get '/' do
  @photos = Photo.all
  erb :index
end
```

---

```
models.rb

require 'data_mapper'

DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/db/photos.db")
class Photo
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :created_at, DateTime
    property :title, String
    property :body, Text
    property :filename, String
    property :description, Text
    property :width, String
    property :height, String
end


DataMapper.finalize

Photo.auto_upgrade!
```

EDIT: It appears that upgrading ruby to 2.2.0 and reinstalling the gems solved the problem

Comment: reinstalling which gem?